# Windows with new Arris modem Stuck on acquiring network address

Tags: networking, windows-xp

**UPDATE:** I have the same issue on Windows 7 with Intel(R) 82578DM Gigabit.  It seems to get stuck for a little less, but it still gets stuck.  Are these network adapter too old?

**ORIGINAL POST:** I have a Windows XP dell desktop from about 2008 with Intel(R) 82566DM-2 Gigabit Network Connection.
Recently I had to upgrade to the modem ARRIS SVG2482AC.
I am connecting to it via a cable (not wireless).

Every time I switch on the computer, it gets stuck in a loop of
"Acquiring network address" and "A network cable is unplugged".
This lasts for a long time, then eventually it gets connected all right.

What can I do to fix this?  I have tried the commands

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```

but to no avail.

Any suggestions?  If there is no fix should I buy a new ethernet card, and what card could fit my 2008 motherboard?

Comment: I would be tempted to try a different network adapter.

Comment: Or try a Linux distro, such as Ubuntu, from a live USB, i.e. test it without installing anything on the HDD. If it can access the modem, you could install it (dual boot or by itself). You'll find Linux safer than XP, and as convenient to use.

Comment: Run far away from XP, it's very exploitable and unpatchable. Ubuntu is a good replacement. You may even be able to emulate your favorite  XP programs from wine.

Comment: Did you register the modem with your carrier? You can't just swap out or install a modem and expect it to work, the carrier needs the RF MAC address authorized in their network or it will not register and function. Depending on the specific model of Arris modem, it may not even give you DHCP without being registered.

Comment: The modem works perfectly with (1) more recent windows 10 laptop, and (2) smartphone.  It works perfectly both with wired and wireless.  In particular it was registered.  On slightly older computers running windows 7 and windows XP it has this awful problem described above.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Does it work if you assign a statically assign the IP information to the computer? Also, this may seem counter productive, but try placing an 10/100 switch (older non-gigabit) between the modem and computer.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to assign the IP information statically?  Regarding your second suggestion, I'll try.  Thank you.

Comment: You need to know an available IP address, subnet, subnet mask, gateway, and DNS servers used on the LAN... then any number of online resources can help, here is one: http://www.1stworks.com/faq/staticipxp.asp but the fact it says "network cable is unplugged" and cycles, I think it's a minor incompatibility with hardware or a cable issue, using a 10/100 switch may fix the issue.

Comment: BTW, I am with other commenters here, drop Windows XP. It is literally dangerous and should not be used in any online capacity, if at all. It should be upgraded or moved to Linux for security. Don't kid yourself, the vulnerabilities of XP are very real.

Comment: I know that linux is superior, but I think it will have the same problem as it sounds like it's the network card that's not recent enough.  What is the rationale why a 10/100 switch may fix the issue?  Thanks.

Comment: Experience... plus the symptoms, it is saying "Network cable unplugged" during the negotiation process, which is not normal. I work with networks in lets just say less than perfect condition daily. There seems to be some inconsistency with older gigabit devices when talking to newer gigabit devices, using a 10/100 switch or configuring equipment not to advertise gigabit capabilities often corrects the issue (the later is usually reserved for enterprise grade equipment, not SOHO).